# LaunchNavigator Ionic2 plugin is not installed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I am new to Ionic 2 and everything around. I'm tryng to setup my first mobile app: touching a button I would open native navigation (Google Maps for Android, for instance). I've installed `launchnavigator` plugin:

```
ionic plugin add uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator
```

and inside cremony.ts page:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LaunchNavigator, LaunchNavigatorOptions } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-ceremony',
  templateUrl: 'ceremony.html'
})
export class Ceremony {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  navigate() {
    let options: LaunchNavigatorOptions = {
      start: ""
    };

    LaunchNavigator.navigate("London, UK", options)
      .then(
      success => alert('Launched navigator'),
      error => alert('Error launching navigator: ' + error)
      );
  }
}
```

make a build `npm run build`and upload it to IonicView with `ionic upload`.
I've do everything like suggested in [this link](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator-example/tree/master/Ionic2Example) but with different luck.

But when I click the button (a simple `<button ion-button (click)="navigate()">Navigate</button>` in the ceremony.html) in the Ionic View an error say: `Error launghing navigator: plugin_not_installed`.

I inspected the project, the `plugins` directory contains `uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigatorlooks` directory. So I look at `package.json` and `config.xml` and I've added the value `uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator` in the `cordovaPlugins`
 and tag `<plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" spec="~3.2.1" />` in the `widget` root. `npm run build`, `ionic upload` but nothing changed.

Where is my error?

Comment: try calling within `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})`

Comment: It looks like Javascript, while my codebase is in Typescript. There's a wya to transalte this into TS?

Comment: typescript is superset of javascript..

Comment: also, does it work with an emulator?

Comment: I know, but I'd like a coherent codebase...
Never tried with an emulator.

Comment: I am not sure of ionic view(havent tried this plugin in it) and the plugin.. try in emulator/device

Comment: you're testing in device or emulator ?

Comment: I thing it indifferent since `launchnavigator.js` is never loaded, at least inspecting it with chrome...

Comment: @marianoc84 error says plugin not installed. So i m wondering whether after adding the plugin to project, did you rebuild the platform once again?

Comment: Instead of manually adding entries to package.json and config.xml, try `ionic plugin add uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator --save` with save option

Comment: @gandhi how to rebuild platform? Npm run build?

Comment: @marianoc84 to rebuild android platform in cordova, the command is: cordova build android But ionic i m not sure, may be ionic build android i guess

Comment: `ionic build android` produce an apk, i tried to install this package, it starts but when it should start the navigation it says: cordova_not_found. I'm confused...

Comment: @marianoc84 i m puzzled with the error message. I m not sure about the installation and building process in Ionic2. But i suggest you to look at this link - https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator/issues/57

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270455/813951

Answer (score 2):

New answer, there is something wrong with your project. Have you modified your index.html file? Is it still including cordova.js? If so what version of Ionic and Cordova are you using?

I made this sample application with your exact code and it works perfectly on both iOS and ANdroid: https://github.com/roblouie/navigator-plugin-test

Did a screen recording on iOS: https://giphy.com/gifs/xTiN0EEQV82aIXWnQI
Just grabbed an image on Android, but it works the same: [image: Android Pic]

Please try the project from github.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova plugins need to be called only once [platform](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/) is ready.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public platform:Platform) {//inject in constructor

  }
```

In your function `navigate()`

```
this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
LaunchNavigator.navigate("London, UK", options)
      .then(
      success => alert('Launched navigator'),
      error => alert('Error launching navigator: ' + error)
      );
});
```

Comment: Nothin changed :(

Comment: @Suraj if its not loaded, then it will give saying LaunchNavigator is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is that you are using Ionic View. Your Ionic app is just html, css, and javascript. However, any plugins you use are written in Java for Android and Objective C for iOS. That plugin source code is then compiled into your app for each platform.

With Ionic View, it only uploads your app, the html, css, and javascript. Nothing is compiled. Ionic View is the app itself, and it loads your code. So no plugins you have are included. Ionic View itself does have some plugins installed on it, and you can see that list here: https://docs.ionic.io/tools/view/#supported-plugins

Unfortunately you will not be able to test any plugin not in that list without building and deploying to a device or emulator.

Comment: I made the `.apk` package (using `ionic build android` command), installed it as a non-trusted package (I haven't store account yet) and when I click the button I get `Error lauching navigator: cordova_not_available`

Comment: @marianoc84 Okay interesting...that's a bit concerning actually, Cordova should definitely be available when running on device. I can maybe dig further later today if no one else solves it before then.