# ionic sqlite porter (plugin_not_installed)

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic3

I followed the tutorial on the link below to create an ionic prepopulated database app but I get plugin_not_installed error.
[ionic prepopulated db tutorial](https://devdactic.com/ionic-sqlite-queries-database/).
Other forums advised uninstalling the plugin and the platform and reinstalling but to no avail after several tries and even creating new ionic projects.

Find attached images of my config.xml file and my ionic info.

```
console.warn: Install the SQLitePorter plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter'
console.error:
 ******[plugin_not_installed error][2]
**************Error plugin_not_installed
```

[plugin list in config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bANWO.png)

Ionic Info:

> cli packages: (MY_DIRECTORY\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

> global packages: cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

```
local packages:
  @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
  Cordova Platforms  : browser 5.0.3 ios 4.5.4
  Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

> System:

```
    Node : v8.9.4
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : Windows 8.1
Environment Variables: ANDROID_HOME : not set
Misc: backend : pro
```

I called the native plugin within platform.ready in case someone wants to ask.
Thank you.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270455/813951

Answer (score 0):

eventually my problem was that I was testing the app with "ionic serve -c" with Ionic DevApp which doesn't load native plugins.
My solution was to build the app to preferred platform (ios in my case) and test in Xcode and it works.