# Media plugin not installed? Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native, cordova-media-plugin

I have an Ionic 3 app that requires to use [Media Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/).

When I press the "record" button on my app, this code block is executed:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.fileName = this.commentsProvider.getFileName(this.platform);
    this.filePath = this.commentsProvider.getFilePath(this.platform, this.fileName);
    this.audio = this.media.create(this.filePath);
    this.audio.startRecord();
    this.recording = true;
});
```

And it doesn't works. The console throws:

```
console.warn: Native: tried accessing the Media plugin but it's not installed.
```

NOTE: I'm runing the app in a connected Android device, via USB.

You can see I'm using `platform.ready()` and anyway I still have this problem.

Any idea?

Thank's in advance!

**EDIT:**  I've already deleted `node_modules` and `plugins` folders, and ran `npm install`, and the problem persists.

Comment: which platform did you try to run?

Comment: on android. (Connected device, no simulator).

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270455/813951

Comment: I'm stuck on same issue. Did you found any solution? Please help.